# aws:sts user for Stack creation - aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli, aws-sam, aws-sts

Using [sam deploy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-deploy.html), where `sam deploy` is a wrapper of `aws cloudformation deploy`, we run below command from EC2, for stack creation:

`aws cloudformation deploy --template-file cfntemplate.yml --stack-name somestack-test --region us-east-1`

Amidst stack creation, we see the below (as shown below):

### [image]

---

user is: `arn:aws:sts::${AccountId}:assumed-role/Autodeploy/i-0000000cc4`. `Autodeploy` is the name of role assigned to EC2. This user disappears after stack creation is complete.

---

---

What does `assumed-role` indicate in its arn?

What does `Autodeploy/i-0000000cc4` indicate in it's arn?

What is `aws:sts` type resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information for your question can be found in the IAM docs reference section *IAM Identifiers* [1].

> The active session of someone assuming the role of "Accounting-Role", with a role session name of "Mary":
>
> arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/Accounting-Role/Mary

The `aws:sts` part indicates that the resource is part of the Security Token Service (STS) [2]. The `assumed-role` part indicates that you are authenticated via a session context which was established most likely by calling something like `aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/Accounting-Role" --role-session-name "Mary"` [3].

In your case: *Autodeploy* is the role name and *i-0000000cc4* is the role session name.

As the cli reference [3] states, **session context** means that you are not authenticated via long-lived credentials but temporary credentials instead:

> By default, the temporary security credentials created by AssumeRole last for one hour. However, you can use the optional DurationSeconds parameter to specify the duration of your session.

#### References

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html
[3] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html

Comment: Is this a user type? Who is creating it? Does this user live until the stack created by sam deploy exist? What is the lifetime of this user?

Comment: Search in your IAM console for the "Autodeploy" role. Is there such a role? I do not know the internal implementation of the SAM CLI utility. Maybe they are deleting the role after deployment, I do not know. Generally, the assumed-role is not a user type. It is a role type, see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html: "An IAM role is similar to an IAM user, in that it is an AWS identity with permission policies that determine what the identity can and cannot do in AWS".

Comment: How to assign role-policy to such dynamic user?

Comment: You could try to use the Resources section of your SAM template and define a resource of type "AWS::IAM::Policy". Use the role name "Autodeploy" for the "Roles"-attribute. If this does not work I guess you should ask a SAM CLI developer on their GitHub or so, because this tends to be a very SAM-specific question.

Comment: Oh man why did you change the whole scope of the question? =( not cool

Comment: Raised separate question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/57343279/3317808