# How to assign a policy to adhoc user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-sam

## Background:

With cross account role `someaccountrole`, I have access to  aws account `xyz`.

---

*Case 1*

To create a stack in account `xyz`, we upload the Cloudformation file through console.

Amidst stack creation in `Events` tab, we see the very first event, as shown below:

### [image]

---

*Case 2*

We create EC2 instance in `xyz` account.

Using [sam deploy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-deploy.html), where `sam deploy` is a wrapper of `aws cloudformation deploy`, we run below command from EC2, for stack creation:

`aws cloudformation deploy --template-file cfntemplate.yml --stack-name somestack-test --region us-east-1`

Amidst stack creation, we see the similar event created (as shown below):

### [image]

---

In case 2, user is: `arn:aws:sts::${AccountId}:assumed-role/Autodeploy/i-0000000cc4`, where we created `Autodeploy` role and assigned to EC2. This user disappears after stack creation is complete.

---

But in **case 2**, user(`i-0000000cc4`) need permission to perform following operations, unlike **case 1**:

```
     {
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:CreateStack",
                "cloudformation:CreateChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:CreateUploadBucket",
                "cloudformation:ExecuteChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:DeleteStack",
                "cloudformation:Describe*",
                "cloudformation:UpdateStack"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:${AccountId}:stack/somestack*”
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
```

otherwise, `Events` tab gives below error in case 2:

```
User: arn:aws:sts::${AccountId}:assumed-role/Autodeploy/i-0000000cc4 
is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:CreateChangeSet on resource:
arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:${AccountId}:stack/somestack-test
```

---

1) In case 1, permissions are given as `someaccountrole`  for stack creation. but in case 2, Why stack creation through AWS CLI require stack creation permission?

2) How to assign an inline policy(short living) to such temporary session resource(`i-0000000cc4`) instead to an EC2??

Comment: I am not able to find anything about the Autodeploy role on the internet. Has somebody an idea where it is created?

Answer (score 1):

> 1) In case 1, permissions are given as someaccountrole for stack creation. but in case 2, Why stack creation through AWS CLI require stack creation permission?

The stack in case 1 is created by the role you specify with the *Permissions* stack option, see [1]. This *AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) service role* usually has the required `cloudformation:...` permissions you listed above.

> 2) How to assign an inline policy(short living) to such temporary session resource(i-0000000cc4) instead to an EC2??

Assigning the policy to the EC2 instance's instance profile is correct!

If you want to run an AWS CLI command from the EC2 instance and you want to use the Instance Metadata service to authenticate your CLI session, you have to attach the required permissions as inline policy of the role which is attached to your EC2 instance via the instance profile.

For more information about the Instance Metadata Service, see [2][3]. For an unofficial but thorough blog post which explains the concepts well, see [4].

#### References

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-console-add-tags.html
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-metadata.html
[3] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html#instance-metadata-security-credentials
[4] https://blog.gruntwork.io/authenticating-to-aws-with-instance-metadata-b6d812a86b40

Comment: For your point: "policy to the EC2 instance's instance profile is correct!" am blocking that EC2 to just run that specific task(`aws cloudformation deploy`).Instead, am thinking to apply policy to the user.

Comment: Is there any other approach to run `sam deploy` command? other than running from EC2.... to allocate resources from SAM template.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-install.html ??

Comment: I do not understand what you need from the EC2 instance which you cannot obtain from your local machine. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: I need administrator permissions as mentioned in your referred link: "Step 2: Create an IAM User with Administrator Permissions' This is not practical. One has to follow some policy rules to work in an account. SAM templates are written by NodeJS, Java, Python developers, not by me. We cannot give them administrator permissions just like that. We fetch the template file produced by them and then run within EC2...

Comment: Actually that is currently an open issue for AWS SAM adoption: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/issues/420. It is possible to specify minimal permission to call sam deploy, but no one knows exactly which permissions are needed because it is not documented well. However, I do not see how you could increase your security in your EC2 scenario further... You could just do one more step: remove the instance profile from the EC2 instance after executing the command on the EC2 instance. This will effectively take away the permissions from the instance for future calls.

Comment: EC2 instance is part of Jenkins pipeline. `sam deploy` command runs round the clock for multiple applications. For your question... what permissions are required? I know the list of all permissions required, because we debugged this problem. After debug, this list of permissions are placed in the policy and placed as part of `Autodeploy` role

Comment: If you know the exact permissions, you can create a user with these permissions and authenticate on your local machine as that user and use cli. But as you wrote that the sam deploy runs as part of a pipeline that is not feasible.
Another approach you could use to limit the lifetime of your EC2 credentials would be to pass down credentials to the instance before executing the sam deploy command. You can use the get-session-token (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/get-session-token.html) command to obtain temporary credentials. You could pass them down to the E2 instance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on creating user? Let me see, if I can fit this approach in pipeline...

Comment: I mean creating a standard IAM user: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users_create.html OR using the role of your Jenkins instance (if it is an EC2 instance).

Comment: The only thing you have to do is to authenticate your CLI. You can do this by setting environment variables, sourcing credentials with external process or cli credentials file (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html#config-settings-and-precedence)! The same page also mentions how to obtain access keys and secret access key for the IAM user under section "To create access keys for an IAM user". Now the point is: You can provision your Jenkins server with those long-lived creds and use them to obtain short-lived creds and pass them down to the EC2 instance.